# Rendering issue with the Listbox control under Windows 7

Tags: winforms, listview, windows-7

We have a couple of winforms applications that host a bunch of icons in a `ListView` control as a handy quick launch down the side of the applications. We also have "XP visual styles" enabled in the project build options for both which works great for Windows XP, but we've had someone highlight that the items in the control are (roughly) twice as wide in one application as the other (normal) when both are run under Windows 7.

As far as I can see in code, both ListViews are added to their respective forms using the windows forms designer, and there doesn't appear to be anything fiddling with the width of the labels (etc.)

I'm a little confused why the two applications/ListViews are behaving differently, and also why there doesn't seem to be anything I can do to affect the width of the items in the `ListView`? What have I missed when checking for differences between the "working" scenario and the "non-working" scenario?

Comment: You need to read this question back yourself.  Subject talks about "listbox".  Question talks about "other" without hint what "other" might be.  No mention of the View property value.  No screenshot.  No answer.

Comment: @Hans "other" is the other of the "couple of winforms applications". Screen shots are an issue, as imgur is blocked by my employer's firewall (and that's before you get into the joys of scrubbing company names and details from the screen shots).

Comment: Did you set the Columns.Width?

Comment: @kpda I'm not setting *any* width in either.

Comment: are you drawing the listbox items via imagelist? you should check the size of the images in the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that setting the `StateImageList` property causes this (even if it is the same image list as used for the normal icons)